# how to fix parsing issue?

Tags: java, parsing

im using jdk se and i keep getting a parsing issue

"error: reached end of file while parsing"

i dont really understand why i keep getting this issue
i have my class closed and brackets in places i think i would need brackets.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class days_in_a_month {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a month:");
String month = input.nextLine();
input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter a year:");
String year = input.nextLine();
input.nextLine();

  boolean isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)||(year % 400 == 0); 

    switch (month){
    case "1":
    case "3":
    case "5":
    case "7":
    case "8":
    case "10":
    case "12":
        System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 31 days"); break;

    case "4":
    case "6":
    case "9":
    case "11":
        System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 30 days"); break;

    case "2":
        if(isLeapYear)
        {
            System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 29 days"); break;
        }
            else
        {
            System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 28 days");
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Add another `}` at the end. And learn how to indent code correctly, so it's more obvious when brackets are mismatched.

Comment: sorry, its my first time posting a question

Comment: That's OK. If you are using an IDE, find out how to get it to format your code. And if you're not using an IDE, start using an IDE.

Comment: i added another } at the end of the code but it's still having parsing errors and now a compilation error??

Comment: I recommend eclipse it would have underlined it and said on the side insert "}"

Comment: [You are having problems with operator precedence](http://ideone.com/cLyUL4): `year % 100 == 0` is parsed as `year % (100 == 0)`, which is invalid because the second operand of `%` is a boolean. You need to insert brackets.

Comment: The problem is not with operator presedence, but with `year` being declared a `String`. You cannot do `%` (or any other arithmetics) on strings.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to solve is using some like this:

```
int year = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

just define **year** variable as **int**:

```
int year = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
```

The problem is that you cannot use % operator for Strings

Here is the full example:

```
package com.yourpackage;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class days_in_a_month {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a month:");
        String month = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter a year:");
        int year = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
        input.nextLine();

        boolean isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);

        switch (month) {
            case "1":
            case "3":
            case "5":
            case "7":
            case "8":
            case "10":
            case "12":
                System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 31 days");
                break;

            case "4":
            case "6":
            case "9":
            case "11":
                System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 30 days");
                break;

            case "2":
                if (isLeapYear) {
                    System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 29 days");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(month + " " + year + " has 28 days");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to name your file for as "**days_in_a_month**" and to define the appopriate **package** in the top of the file!

Comment: Never would have considered that with out pasting it into eclipse :)

Comment: I did that, but I'm still having compilation errors ideone.com/CvMXDD

Comment: Provided full example. Just double-check the file naming and package definition.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to use `%` operator with String

```
boolean isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
```

Operator `%` can't be used with String

Answer (score 0):

The Best of The Best solve is:

```
package com.dayinmonth

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class days_in_a_month {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a month:");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter a year:");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);

        System.out.println(String.format("%d %d has %d days", date.getMonthValue(), date.getYear(), date.lengthOfMonth()));

    }
}
```